# Inline images, im using bootstrap "row" and "col-md-3"

Tags: image, inline

How can i inline images? i am using bootstrap row, and per image have a class of "col-md-3".

[image]

the problem is, as you can see, the 5th image goes to the right, it should be on the left, underneath the IMPOSSIBRU image.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because your images have different heights. If you are able to restrict height to a certain 'px' then this might help to resolve the problem.

When using cols to group a bunch of things, it's always good to try and keep layouts + sizes the same to prevent this kind of thing happening.

Comment: thanks. but is there any other way that i can force the next image into the left? let's say that i dont care if they're different sizes.

Comment: Yes, but it would have to be on a new row. So you can close the div row after the first 4 columns and start a new div row to add the 5th col, 6th col etc. this should force it to start from the left. But, if you do this, you will no longer get that 'fitting' behaviour that bootstrap has done in your screenshot. This masonry type layout is given by bootstrap auto if the cols are in one contained div.